# PHP Not Displaying How I'd Expect

Tags: php

**EDIT: I've found the source of the problem. It was the webserver, but it was the way that the webserver was processing my requests via my index page. In other words, a foolish mistake on my part. I only discovered this because of the comments in this thread, however, so thank you.**

I've recently started taking a PHP class for school, however I can't seem to get any of my PHP to work. We are supposed to upload our projects to a provided website via FTP, so PHP and all necessary pieces should already be setup on the website. For my first project, I was basically instructed to copy/paste a piece from the textbook and upload it. Even this did not work, coming back with a "No input file specified" error. The code for that was:

```
     <?php
        //Get current time in a readable format
        $currentTime = date( "M j, Y g:i:s a" );
        //Display greeting and time
        echo "Hello, world! The current time is $currentTime";
     ?>
```

I assumed it was something that would fix itself with time and moved on. Just now, I was working on the next exercise, it stated to create a file with the following code:

```
<?php
      $radius = 4;

      $diameter = $radius * 2;
      $circumference = M_PI * $diameter;
      $area = M_PI * pow( $radius, 2 );

      echo "This circle has... <br /> ";
      echo "A radius of " . $radius . " <br /> ";
      echo "A diameter of " . $diameter . " <br /> ";
      echo "A circumference of " . $circumference . " <br /> ";
      echo "An area of " . $area . " <br /> ";
?>
```

However when I tried opening this to check and see if it worked, it returned the following:

```
 "; echo "A radius of " . $radius . " 
 "; echo "A diameter of " . $diameter . " 
 "; echo "A circumference of " . $circumference . " 
 "; echo "An area of " . $area . " 
 "; ? >
```

This result... doesn't even make sense to me. At all. Even if it was just pasting my lines as plain text they aren't formatted like that. I understand this is probably an entirely basic question to be asking but I'm just starting PHP and none of this makes sense. None of it is explained either.

EDIT: I've been asked for a bit more information, so here is what I can give.

For the first example, I uploaded it to the webserver via FileZilla and when I opened the webpage, the only text was an unformatted "No input file specified." When I hit "View Source Code", the source code also said simply "No input file specified", despite the fact that I definitely uploaded a .php file with code in it to the webserver.

For the second example, it is clear to me that I messed up, as I simply tried opening the file in Google Chrome, not associated with any webserver. I had no idea you couldn't do that, and honestly that seems fairly inefficient, but I guess it can't be helped.

There is yet a third example that I just uploaded to the server now. An actual exercise that is a part of the homework for the class. The file I uploaded had this exact code:

```
<html>

<body>

<?php
    $x = 4;

    $x = $x + 1;
    $x += 1;
    $x++;

    echo $x;
?>

</body>

</html>
```

This file *also* returns "No input file specified."

Comment: Try 'View Source' in your browser. Do you see your PHP file?

Comment: To add to halfer's comment, if you *do* see your php file, then it isn't being processed by the server-side PHP processor; you should see only the output.

Comment: Here's a SWAG:  The "no input file specified" message is coming from your FTP client and your file never got to the server.  Please edit your question to tell us *how* you transferred your file to the server.

Comment: @BoBBrown, I edited the post and as said in the edits, I used FileZilla for all file transfers, as recommended by my school.

Comment: Your first two PHP examples are OK as you've posted them, but apparently something is going wrong with your file transfer.  Please add to the question the exact URL you're putting into your web browser when you test from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how you start getting input *right after* the first `>` in your code.

This is a sure sign that PHP isn't processing your file.

Did you name your file `something.php`? It needs that `.php` extension, or else custom configuration, or else it won't handle it.

Comment: It is named .php, in the case of the second file, the file name is simply, "test.php"

Comment: Both of your examples work as specified on my PHP server.  If you are absolutely, positively *sure* that your files have the `.php` extension, it is time to contact your instructor.

Comment: @BobBrown, alrighty, I suppose you're right. I've just been opening the files as is on my computer. I guess you can't do that? When I do that, if it works properly, I get a blank page. On the webserver, I get "No Input File Specified", but I have no idea how to fix either of those since I'm not the server host.

Comment: Nope... you have to put the files on the server because that's where the PHP processor is.  Please edit your question to describe exactly the steps you took for the first of your two examples, including what you tried with your web browser.  (We can help you, but there's not enough information yet.)

Comment: @user3530169: what URL are you using? Make sure it begins with `http://` and not `file://`.

Answer (score 0):

Are others having the same problem?  If the files are named *.php then perhaps the PHP module is not enabled on the web server or the web server is somehow otherwise configured incorrectly.

Comment: I have no way of really knowing that, I'm afraid. I've tried messaging my teacher but unfortunately the webserver keeps rejecting my emails as well. It's quite a glorious setup, I must say.

Comment: Your instructor's email address is almost certainly not on the web server you're using for your coursework.  Your course syllabus should have instructions for contacting the instructor, but let's explore the FTP theory a bit before you do that.